# Acts 21:36 different sentiment in NLT

Tags: contradiction, acts, nlt

I most commonly read out of NKJV & NLT . I’m reading through Acts 21 when verse 36 sticks out to me how almost every other translation reads “Away with him!”  Yet NLT reads “Kill Him, Kill, Him” the original Greek seems to align more with the majority of versions. Why does NLT make this jump?

Comment: @DavidHernandez-Welcome! It is better to write the Question as a question beginning with an interrogative. (Who, what, when, why, where?) It makes it easier for the reader to follow your query....To add in your research, consider that the New Living Translation is not a "literal" version , but a paraphrase to summarize the thoughts of the biblical writer so the modern English reader can catch the drift better in modern vernacular. Keep studying the Bible. It's great for the soul!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the original Greek does not mean "kill".

The NLT is more of a paraphrase than a literal translation.
The translators obviously thought that a mob screaming "Kill him" better conveyed what was happening than having people yelling for him to be carried away.
An angry mob will often use exaggerated demands to make their point, so the NLT isn't necessarily wrong, only not literally correct.

The NKJV is very literal and forms a good combination with the NLT.
If the two agree in meaning, it's likely correct.
If they disagree, then one should look at several other translations, or even at the original Greek, to determine the originally intended meaning.

> #### Translation philosophy
>
> The New Living Translation used translators from a variety of Christian denominations. The method combined an attempt to translate the original texts simply and literally with a dynamic equivalence synergy approach used to convey the thoughts behind the text where a literal translation may have been difficult to understand or even misleading to modern readers. A part of the reasoning behind adapting the language for accessibility is the premise that more people will hear the Bible read aloud in a church service than are likely to read it or study it on their own.
>
> It has been suggested that this "thought-for-thought" methodology, while making the translation easier to understand, is less accurate than a literal (formal equivalence) method, and thus the New Living Translation may not be suitable for those wishing to undertake detailed study of the Bible.
> — [New Living Translation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Living_Translation#Translation_philosophy)

Comment: I think that translating 'away with him' as 'kill him' is a step too far, given that the original language has words for both. This is why we need to be wary of paraphrase Bibles. They actually obfuscate the meaning and make it more difficult to understand the original content.

Answer (score 0):

Some lexical authorities render this as calling for his death. In context this would appear to be exactly what they were doing. Check out Thayer and BAGD.